# Help with a bottombar

Tags: css

i have been trying to implement a bottombar for my site, however the vision i have seems to me to be rather difficult. Maybe you can enlighten me?

I want to have a bottombar that sits at the bottom of the browser window if the content does not spill over the edge, but if the content does spill over i want the bottombar at the bottom of the content.
I would prefer if it was CSS solution but it might be better/easier in something else, i dont know. Also no PHP.

I hope you understand me.

And thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Thanks Joe, this seems to be exactly what im looking for.
Im having some problems implementing it though. But thanks for the point in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the height of the bottom bar is fixed it's fairly simple. eg.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #content { min-height: 100%; }
        * html #content { height: 100%; } /* IE6 hack */
        #trailer { height: 2em; margin-top: -2em; background: yellow; }
        #pad { height: 2em; }
    </style>
</head><body>
    <div id="content">
        Content content content content content content content content content content content.
        <div id="pad"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="trailer">
        Bit at the bottom.
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick, (*note that the extra wrapping div with some `padding-bottom` is required in order to make sure the footer does not overlap the contents*),

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sticky Footer Test</title>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        * { 
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #container {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height/**/: 100%; /* for IE6 */
            background: #ddd;
        }

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            background: #555;
            margin-top: -100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #content {
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Hello! I'm some content!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Hello! I'm a footer!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```